# How to append an element to an Iterator in scala

Tags: scala, iterator

I want to append an element to the end of an iterator like this:

```
val a = Iterator(3, 4)
val b = a + 5 // expect b == Iterator(3,4,5), but there is no + method
val b2 = a ++ Iterator(5) // That works, but not concise.
```

Is there a better way than `b2` to make this?

Comment: Iterator doesn't have any method to add an element to it in a concise way, you can convert it to list if you want it. Or else this is the only option you've got.

Comment: Better according to which criterion?

Comment: You might use `padTo()` but you'd need to know the length of `a` before you could `a.padTo(aLen+1,5)` and asking an `Iterator` for its length consumes it. So, no, not a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can always just hide the not-concise syntax behind something that you like better.

```
implicit class IterPlus[A](itr: Iterator[A]) {
  def +(elem: A) = itr ++ Iterator(elem)
}

val a = Iterator(3, 4)
val b = a + 5          //Iterator(3, 4, 5)
```